# in delayed_job, are hooks called when Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs is false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, delayed-job

I'm using [collectiveidea/delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). In my RSpec tests, the [:before, :after, :success] hooks aren't getting called as I would expect.

When `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = true` (the default), I see the `enqueue()` hook getting called and nothing more.  This is the behavior I expect, since there's no separate task processing the jobs.

But when `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false`, as recommended for testing by the documents, I see my process() method getting called, but none of of the hooks.

If this is not the expected behavior, any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?  (I can easily include code.)  If this is the expected behavior, then what's a strategy for testing the hooks?

[Side note: The spec directory for delayed_job, notably the [performable_method_spec tests](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/spec/performable_method_spec.rb), suggest that you can set `Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = false` and still get callbacks to your hooks.  But those tests are using the `obj.delay.method` construct rather than `Delayed::Job.enqueue(object_with_a_perform_method)` to enqueue the job.  Would this make a difference?]

[Update: I've tried the `obj.delay.method` form as well as the `Delayed::Job.enqueue(obj_with_a_perform_method)` form -- I don't see the hooks getting called in either case.]

Comment: I don't know anything about this gem, but if you don't get a good answer here, try looking into the source, where these hooks are being called. Maybe the code isn't too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [collectiveidea/delayed_job github page](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/208), I found this very same bug described, fixed, and pulled.  Presumably an updated version of delayed_job will fix the problem.

Update: I've found a workaround other than pulling the latest version.  You can explicitly call the Delayed::Job worker method.  It will process items in the queue -- in the same thread as the tests of course -- but the callback hooks do get called:

```
[successes, failures] = Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
```